# Undefined variable in ceaser cipher -Python

Tags: python, variables, encryption, undefined

```
 import sys
 import string

 array = []

while True:

input = raw_input("Please enter no more than 10 characters, one per line, and terminate the message by entering % ")

def main():
     key = 3
     message = input
     cryptMessage = ""
     for ch in message:
           cryptMessage = cryptMessage + chr(ord(ch) + key)

if input == "%"

print array, len(array), "The coded message is:", cryptMessage 
sys.exit(1) #This tells the program to exit
array.append(input)
main()
```

Basically I have everything working the way I want it to except for printing the user input text in encrypted form. It already prints in regular form, I want it to print in both regular and encrypted forms. It keeps saying that the cryptMessage variable in the print line is undefined. I thought I had defined it in the code above but apparently not. What am I missing?

Comment: You have `def main():` in the while loop? Also please fix tour indentation.

Comment: I will fix the indentation, but I still do not know why the cryptMessage is undefined. I have ran just the encryption part before and have not gotten that error.

Comment: Without correct indentation here, its difficult to understand how your program should behave. In python, indentation is crucial for proper execution. Without this, its difficult to see any structure/logic in your code spinet.

Comment: Is that any better? I apologize for how unclear it is, all I am trying to find out is how to print the users text in the encrypted form.

Answer (score 0):

I re-worked your code a little bit.  The reason you were getting an undefined variable error is because you were defining the `cryptMessage` in your `main()` function, and it was not accessible outside of that.

```
import sys

# these can be declared up here
array = []
key = 3

# loop until the user tells us not to
while True:

     # grab the input from the user
    input = raw_input("Please enter no more than 10 characters, one per line, and terminate the message by entering % ")

    # the string we'll fill
    cryptMessage = ""

    # go over the input and 'cypher' it
    for ch in input:
        cryptMessage += chr(ord(ch) + key)

    # add this line of message to the array
    array.append(cryptMessage)

    # when the user tells us to stop
    if input == "%":

        # print and break out of the while loop
        print "The coded message is:", ' '.join(array)
        break
```

Output:

```
Please enter no more than 10 characters, one per line, and terminate the message by entering % tyler
Please enter no more than 10 characters, one per line, and terminate the message by entering % is 
Please enter no more than 10 characters, one per line, and terminate the message by entering % my
Please enter no more than 10 characters, one per line, and terminate the message by entering % name
Please enter no more than 10 characters, one per line, and terminate the message by entering % %
The coded message is: w|ohu lv# p| qdph (
```

Comment: Wow that helps a lot thank you! Is there a way I could keep the original array that displays the plaintext results, and then show the coded message in addition to the plaintext result?

Comment: You could just have another separate array to store all of the original text.  Basically do everything the same as the `array` you have now, but in the loop `append(input)` instead of `append(cryptMessage)`

Comment: Is there any way to elminate the ( symbol from appearing when printing the contents of the array?

Comment: Its part of your encrypted message.  Its what `%` becomes after you apply your transformation.  You could add some logic in the while loop to not add it to the list.